# Laravel 5.4: How do I get records from just this week?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

To get all records of the current day, I did

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$dataToday = Data::whereDay('created_at', $dt->day)->get();
```

To get records from this week, I tried the following but without success.

```
$dataThisWeek = Data::where('created_at', $dt->weekOfYear);
$dataThisWeek = Data::where('created_at', $dt->weekOfMonth);
$dataThisWeek = Data::whereWeek('created_at', $dt->week);
```

How do we approach this with Eloquent and Carbon (preferably) or a native MYSQL function?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
Data::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get();
```

To set the week start/end:

```
Carbon::setWeekStartsAt(Carbon::SUNDAY);
Carbon::setWeekEndsAt(Carbon::SATURDAY);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try

```
$dataThisWeek = Data::where(\DB::raw("WEEKOFYEAR(created_at)"), $dt->weekOfYear)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason using Laravel 7.4^ the accepted solution above is not working on my end. No data is shown, to fix it I added a format like this:

```
$now = Carbon::now();

Data::whereBetween("created_at", [
   $now->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'), //This will return date in format like this: 2022-01-10
   $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d')
])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete @user320487 answer:

To avoid conflict between different third-party libraries, static setters should not be used. Use $weekEndsAt optional parameter instead when using endOfWeek method.

```
Data::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(Carbon::SATURDAY)])->get();
```

You can also use the 'first_day_of_week' locale setting to change the start of week according to current locale selected and implicitly the end of week.