# Laravel: write query to count sales with group by weeks

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have mysql database having a sales table, representing a list of products sold daily, with columns of product name, price and created_at. I could get the number of sales for a certain day by doing this for instance;

```
$sales = Sale::where('created_at', $certain_day')->count();
```

However, i need to track the sales per week for a number of weeks, say the number of products sold from the beginning of this week (sunday) till date, the number of sales last week, the number of sales two weeks ago and so on, for the last five weeks, returned as an array (something like this:[{30/12/2021: 10}, {25/12/2021: 15}, {18/12/2021: 22}]. How can i write laravel eloquent query to achieve this?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473685/laravel-5-4-how-do-i-get-records-from-just-this-week

Comment: @DevsiOdedra i want the record returned per week, not just a week record.

Comment: like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024504/laravel-sort-the-result-are-grouped-by-weeks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$from = date('2018-01-01');
$to = date('2018-05-02');

Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Then you can use Carbon method for current week, previous week, next week

```
Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get();
```

@update

```
Sale::selectRaw('*,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) DIV '.$sec. ' as group_date')->groupBy('group_date');
```

For week,month and day you can do

```
->groupBy(function($data) {
// day
return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
//month
return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('Y-m');
//week
return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('W');
})
```

Comment: thanks..this returns just a record for the week. What i want is a record showing the count of sales for each week of the past five weeks, i.e, for this week, for last week, for 2 weeks ago and so on, all returned in a single query

Comment: SELECT *  FROM `sales` WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
Can you please try this directly in db, If you are getting desire records then i will help you to transform in laravel

Comment: thanks. But this only returns the records for the last week. If i can explain, i want a record for each of the past weeks, group per week and not just a week. More like saying i want a record for the sales for this week, last week, last two weeks etc returned in a single query. (What i really want is the count of records per week)

Comment: I think you should try this:

Sale::selectRaw('*,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) DIV '.$sec. ' as group_date')->groupBy('group_date');

and For week,month and day you can do

->groupBy(function($data) {
// day
return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
//month
return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('Y-m');
//week
return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('W');
})

Answer (score 0):

This following query gives you the last 5 weeks with the count of sales in each week:

```sql
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(created_at) - MOD(TO_DAYS(created_at), -1, 7)) AS weeklyGrouping , COUNT(*) AS sales_count
FROM sales
GROUP BY weeklyGrouping
ORDER BY weeklyGrouping DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The formula above assumes that Sunday is the first day of the week and in case your weeks start on Mondays, change the -1 to -2.

for descriptive information you can refer to [this article](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/).

EDIT (Eloquent query builder Style)

```php
$sales = Sale::selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS sales_count')
    ->selectRaw('FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(created_at) - MOD(TO_DAYS(created_at), -1, 7)) AS weeklyGrouping')
    ->groupBy('weeklyGrouping')
    ->orderBy('weeklyGrouping', 'DESC')
    ->take(5);
```